# Get seekbar progress for calculation in another file Android

Tags: java, android, seekbar

This may be a very stupid question (which it's got like 99% chance it is) but I can't figure this out for the life of me.  I've got a seekbar in one activity, we'll call it **Activity 1**, and I need to use it's constantly changing value (progress) in another activity, we'll call it **Activity 2**, for calculations (or maybe I can do the calculations in the first activity and then just send the value over to the second one, IDK which would be better).

So here's my **Activity 1** code:

```
public class Painting extends Activity
{
    SeekBar curveBar;
    SampleView sampleView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_painting);

        curveBar = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.curveBar);
        sampleView = new SampleView(this);

        curveBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            int progressChangedValue = 0;
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                if (progress >= 50) //prints out 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100
                {
                    progressChangedValue = progress;
                }
                else if (progress < 50) //prints out -40, -30, -20, -10, 0
                {
                    progressChangedValue = (-1) * (progress);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {}

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                Toast.makeText(Painting.this, "Value: " +  progressChangedValue, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

and here's my RELEVANT **Activity 2** code:

```
public class SampleView extends View
{
    private Paint mPaint;
    private float mX;
    private float[] mPos;

    private Path mPath;
    private Paint mPathPaint;

    private static final int DY = 30;
    private static final String TEXTONPATH = "Along a path";


public SampleView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);
        setFocusable(true);

        mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mPaint.setTextSize(90);
        mPaint.setTypeface(Typeface.SERIF);

        mPath = new Path();
        makePath(mPath);

        mPathPaint = new Paint();
        mPathPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mPathPaint.setColor(Color.rgb(255,0,0));
        mPathPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    }


    public SampleView(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
        setFocusable(true);

        mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mPaint.setTextSize(90);
        mPaint.setTypeface(Typeface.SERIF);

        mPath = new Path();
        makePath(mPath);

        mPathPaint = new Paint();
        mPathPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mPathPaint.setColor(Color.rgb(255,0,0));
        mPathPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    }

public void makePath(Path p)  //<----- this is where i need the seekbar's value
//so that i can make this take more variables so that the seekbar
//adjusts the values in the p.cubicTo's below
    {
//            p.moveTo(250, -300);
        p.moveTo(0,0);
//            p.cubicTo(-250, -550, 750, -550, 250, -300);

            p.cubicTo(0,-400,600,-400,600,0); //semi-circle?
//            p.cubicTo(-600, -400, 600, -400, 0, 0); //as far as the curve probably should allow
//        p.cubicTo(0, 0, 0, 0, 620,0); //flat line
    }
```

I have tried to use `curvebar.getProgress()` on both the first activity and the second activity but I can't get it unless I'm within the `OnSekbarChangeListener`.  I've tried setting public variables to the value but it only changes if i set the value within the listener, otherwise it doesn't (which makes perfect sense).  I've tried setting the seekbar to be static (although I probably didn't do it right) and that didn't work either.  I just can't figure out how i can get that value out and use it in the second file.

I would really appreciate some help

Thank you

Comment: Activity 2 is not an activity but a custom view. You need to add it to your activity correctly by inflating the view, calling the c'tor is not the way to do this. Then you'll change makePath to have an integer as a parameter so you can use it the way you want.

Comment: @NeriaNachum i don't understand what you mean.  can you please elaborate with some code?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I cannot give you a thorough answer in a SO comment. My primary point is that you don't have two activities but two views inside an activity, of which one is a `SeekBar`. Hence I suggest you to follow tutorials for the following: 1. Simple `SeekBar` tutorial. 2. Adding a custom view to activity programmatically. Google it.

Comment: Moreover, you didn't mention what you're trying to achieve, but I'm very skeptical that you really need a custom view with a custom behavior. Try to look for existing views (whether on Android Developers or on Github) that may suit your needs and your work will become much simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a public method in your SampleView class that can take the seekbar's progress as a parameter.

```
public class SampleView extends View {
    ...
    public void updatePath(int seekBarProgress) {
        // Do whatever you need to with the passed in value here.
    }
    ...
}
```

Then in your Activity you can call this method to update the SampleView with the latest progress value.

```
public class Painting extends Activity {
    ...
    curveBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
            ...
            sampleView.updatePath(progress);
            ...
        }
        ...     
    }
}
```

Comment: i've taken what you said and i can now get the value of the seekbar's progress in my SampleView.  how can i use it to constantly update my `makePath` function? Meaning: in my new `updatePath()` function i've set a public INT value to be the `seekbarProgress` parameter multiplied by 6.  How can i now put this value into the `makePath()` function if i update the function to be `makePath(Path p, int x3)` where the `x3` would be one or more of the values in the `p.cubicTo()` function?